# How to show a forwarded jsp on fancybox?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is it possible to displaying a jsp which forwarded by a servlet on a fancybox?

Following is what I am trying, but it doesn't work

**js:**

```
$('.showDetail').fancybox();
```

**html:**

```
<a class="showDetail" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/employee/emp.do?empId=${empId}"> ${average}</a>
```

Comment: Can you post the html that gets generated in your HTML (i.e. JSP?) section? I am thinking this is a JS problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('.showDetail').fancybox({
    type: "ajax"
});
```

or via html, add the class `fancybox.ajax`

```
<a class="showDetail fancybox.ajax" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/employee/emp.do?empId=${empId}"> ${average}</a>
```

**NOTE**: this for v2.x

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Would you explain what 'via html' mean?

Comment: via html means that if you add the class `fancybox.ajax` in your html code (your `<a>` tag), you don't need to add `type: "ajax"` in your js code